# Silverstripe: can't install Lumberjack module via composer

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe

I have a Silverstripe website and I need to install the Lumberjack module,
after typing:

```
composer require silverstripe/lumberjack
```

I get the following error

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package silverstripe/framework (installed at 3.6.5, required as 3.6.2) is satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[3.6.5] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability.

Can someone explain what's happening ? I've pretty much tried installing every version of Lumberjack.

Comment: What does the contents of your `composer.json` file look like?

Comment: What version of SilverStripe are you running?